# Binding a List of Lists to a dataGridView

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, datagridview

I have defined a List (called blockList) which `contains 3 objects` of Type List (called rowList) which contains 2 objects of Type Record.
In a dataGridView I want to display one of the `3 blocks` at one time i.e. a `2 x 2 Array.`

The display of the block should be controlled by a numericalUpDown Control.

When only `bs.CurrencyManager.Position` is changed in `numUpDown_ValueChanged` the dataGridView will not be updated as I expected. This is done only if the second line in this method is uncommented.
One additional problem is that the last line in dataGridview which `allows adding of new lines disappears`. Setting the `allowNew-Property` did not help.

I do have the dim feeling that my hole approach how I implemented data binding is not OK.

**My code:**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<Record> rowList;
    public List<List<Record>> blockList;

    public BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int rowListLength = 2;
        int blockListLength = 3;
        blockList = new List<List<Record>>(blockListLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < blockListLength; i++)
        {
            blockList.Add(new List<Record>());
            blockList[i] = new List<Record>(rowListLength);
            for (int j = 0; j < rowListLength; j++)
                blockList[i].Add(new Record(10 * i + j, "name_" + (10 * i + j).ToString()));
        }

        dg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dg.Columns["ID"].ReadOnly = false;
        dg.Columns["ID"].DataPropertyName = "ID";
        dg.Columns["Customer"].DataPropertyName = "Customer";

        bs.DataSource = typeof(List<List<Record>>);
        foreach (List<Record> block in blockList)
            bs.Add(block);
        bs.CurrencyManager.Position = 0;
        dg.DataSource = (List<Record>)bs.CurrencyManager.Current;
    }

    private void numUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bs.CurrencyManager.Position = (int)numUpDown.Value;
        //dg.DataSource = (List<Record>)bs.CurrencyManager.Current;
    }
}

public class Record
{
    public Record(int id, string customer)
    {
        ID = id;
        Customer = customer;
    }
    public Decimal? ID { get; set; }       
    public string Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `public Form1()` i commented the following

Here's is the whole Code:

```
namespace listoflist
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<Record> rowList;
        public List<List<Record>> blockList;

        public BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int rowListLength = 2;
            int blockListLength = 3;
            blockList = new List<List<Record>>(blockListLength);
            for (int i = 0; i < blockListLength; i++)
            {
                blockList.Add(new List<Record>());
                blockList[i] = new List<Record>(rowListLength);
                for (int j = 0; j < rowListLength; j++)
                    blockList[i].Add(new Record(10 * i + j, "name_" + (10 * i + j).ToString()));
            }

            //dg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            //dg.Columns["ID"].ReadOnly = false;
            //dg.Columns["ID"].DataPropertyName = "ID";
            //dg.Columns["Customer"].DataPropertyName = "Customer";

            bs.DataSource = typeof(List<List<Record>>);
            foreach (List<Record> block in blockList)
                bs.Add(block);
            bs.CurrencyManager.Position = 0;
            dg.DataSource = (List<Record>)bs.CurrencyManager.Current;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bs.CurrencyManager.Position = (int)numUpDown.Value;
            dg.CurrentCell = dg.Rows[Math.Min(dg.CurrentRow.Index + bs.CurrencyManager.Position, dg.Rows.Count - 1)].Cells[dg.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];

        }
    }

    public class Record
    {
        public Record(int id, string customer)
        {
            ID = id;
            Customer = customer;
        }
        public Decimal? ID { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Tnx for your. But I'm sorry, that it seems not to work for me.

Comment: :Tnx for your help. But I'm sorry, that it seems not to work for me. Only  the first of my three block is displayed in  `dg`.The other two blocks show up only  if the original commented line in `numUpDown_ValueChanged` is reactivated again. The additional line for the creation of new lines is still not visible. So the behviour is basically the same as before. Sorry my previous comment has been posted unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have solved my problem but I'm not totally happy with my solution.
Every time a new block is to be displayed the old block in `bs`is cleared and replaced by the new block (see `displayNewBlock`). So `bs` never knows the blocklist as a whole but only one element of this list.
At the outset I did hope that I would find a way to make the complete data set available to the `BindingSource` and then find a way to make that part of the data required for display available to the  `dataGridView`.
Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        // Initialisations left out
        dg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dg.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        dg.Columns["ID"].DataPropertyName = "ID";
        dg.Columns["Customer"].DataPropertyName = "Customer";

        bs.DataSource = typeof(List<Record>);
        bs.AllowNew = true;
        dg.DataSource = bs;

        displayNewBlock(0);
    }

    private void numUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        displayNewBlock((int)numUpDown.Value);
    }

    private void displayNewBlock(int blockIndex)
    {
        bs.Clear();
        foreach (Record row in blockList[(int)numUpDown.Value])
            bs.Add(row);
    }
```